# Does defining nested functions forbidden in Julia?

Tags: julia

I can say I've never seen any package maintainer define nested functions so far:

```
function foo()
    function bar()
        # do
    end
    # do
end
```

Is it forbidden in Julia, or can it cause performance reduction?

Comment: As is easily checked, it isn't forbidden. The `bar` function is only in scope inside the `foo` function which limits its usefullness. Often, anonymous functions can serve the same purpose and save the programmer another tiring naming decision :-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand on DanGetz response:

1. It is allowed.
2. It does not impact performance if used correctly.
3. It can impact performance or code correctness if used incorrectly (especially if you capture variables from outer scope), so you need to be careful.
4. Within functions defining anonymous functions is much more common.

If you want to learn more about the potential performance impact see [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#man-performance-captured).